# Define "injected"

Tags: windows, input

Reading the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct

The bit 4 (counting from 0), is defined as - "Specifies whether the event was injected. The value is 1 if that is the case; otherwise, it is 0. Note that bit 1 is not necessarily set when bit 4 is set."

What is the actual definition of "injected event?" in this context?

You'd think it was an easier thing to google.

Comment: Guess: added using an API like SendInput / SendKeys instead of coming from the device driver.

Comment: Stuff that the user did not generate.  SendInput() produces injected events.

Comment: Cool. That's what I suspected. If either of you would like to put that as an answer I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Microsoft's documentation for the  SendInput function it describes what it does as inserting or injecting input:

"The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream.  .... This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level."

Keyboard input generated by the user and sent from the device driver will not have the bit set.  Input created using API functions will have the bit set.